# Change Navbar to fixed in Scroll using VueJS

Tags: html, jquery, css, vue.js

I have a simple question How to Create a Fixed Navbar on Scrolling using Vue

I create a jQuery code but I want to migrate to Vue

I updated my code to Vue JS in File called navbar.js

**jQuery CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function fixedHeader() {

    var windows = $(window);
    var screenSize = windows.width();
    var sticky = $('#f-navbar');
    var $html = $('html');
    var $body = $('body');

    windows.on('scroll', function () {
        var scroll = windows.scrollTop();
        var headerHeight = sticky.height();

        if (screenSize >= 320) {
            if (scroll < headerHeight) {
                sticky.removeClass('is-sticky');
            } else {
                sticky.addClass('is-sticky');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Vue JS Code**

```
const navbar = new Vue({
    el: '#f-navbar',
    data: function fixedHeader() {
        return {
            stickyNavbar: {
                isSticky: false
            }
        }
    },
    mounted() {

    },
    methods: {
        handleScrolling () {

        }
    }
});
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<nav id="f-navbar" class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white"
     v-bind:class="stickyNavbar"></nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready is about similar to Vue's `mounted` hook but applies on Component.

In your Navbar.vue `<script>`

```
mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.getWindowWidth);
  },
data() {
    return {
      screenSize: 0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getWindowWidth() {
      this.screenSize= window.innerWidth;
    },
  },
```

at your `<template>` for NavBar component,

assign your `:class` according your condition

`<nav :class="{'is-sticky': screenSize == 320}">`

UPDATE: is-sticky class only shows when scrollPosition = 320 in window's width size.

Comment: I want fixed navbar class only in scroll with Screen Size 320

Comment: Oh my bad, i thought u wanted scrollY (the scrollbar height), letme update screensize instead

Comment: There we go, lemme know is that you need. Pretty much `window` + `resize` event will work as Vue is Javascript. Cheers

Comment: you can take a look to the jQuery code change the navbar to fixed when scrolling with a specific resize screen size 320 and back to default navbar in 0 that's what i need please

Comment: @Hammouda Houssam Please recheck my first reply, it's updated and tested working from mine. Please marked as 'answered' if solved. Cheers

Comment: I added full Github Gist with my version of code: https://gist.github.com/SayChunKim/dbb4ad06819d4c994c517c71c6ab1628

Comment: I try all these but nothing show when I want to scrolling down ?? I add my own JS code take a look

Comment: Scrolling Down means you're referring Scrollbar instead of Window widthSize? The difference is between `innerWidth` for device/window's widthSize and `scrollY` is for scrollBar vertically. My code was meant for your window width = 320. 

And your data should not have `fixedHeader()` but put under `methods` instead, please check my gist.github link above.